# XNA C# Issue with Keyboard Array

Tags: c#, arrays, xna, keyboard-events

I've started making a `Player` class for my game, so due to the amount of controls for the game I used the Key's array into a switch to make it simple. It works properly with all keys except for one.

When I press Space Bar and The Arrow Keys, it only detects one of the arrow keys and the space bar at the same time. But it only occurs with the space bar. I was trying to solve this but I commented the space part and it does the same.

It doesn't happen if i use the `isDown` method.

Here is the code:

```
for (int Key = 0; Key < Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys().Count(); Key++)
{
    switch (Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys()[Key])
    {
        case Keys.Up:
            Move(Direction.Up);
            Console.WriteLine("Up");
            break;
        case Keys.Down:
            Move(Direction.Down);
            Console.WriteLine("Down");
            break;
        case Keys.Left:
            Move(Direction.Left);
            Console.WriteLine("Left");
            break;
        case Keys.Right:
            Move(Direction.Right);
            Console.WriteLine("Right");
            break;
        case Keys.LeftShift:
            if (!isShifting)
                isShifting = true;
            break;
        case Keys.A:
            if (!oldKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                CastSkill(1);
            break;
        case Keys.Space:
            shootMgr.Shoot();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does pressing the space bar and arrow key at the same time works elsewhere? There's a physical limitation on your keyboard on which keys you can press together.

Comment: Yes, it works in any other game or application

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do it in ifs instead of your for and switch.

```
var keys = Keyboard.GetState();

if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) {
    Move(Direction.Up);
    Console.WriteLine("Up");
}
if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) {
    ...
}
```

But if you wanted to do it with a loop and switch, what happens when you switch it around to:

```
var keys = Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys();
for (var i = 0; i < keys.Count(); i++) {
    switch (keys[i]) {
        case: Keys.Up:
            ...
            break;
        case: Keys.Down:
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```

I believe your problem is coming from calling and receiving a new array from GetPressedKeys() each iteration of your loop.

Comment: I used now the IsKeyDown method and it does the same with the space bar :/

Comment: I tested the input in a new project and it does the same. The space bar is doing the same with the other keys.

Comment: it seems to not work in some engines like Multimedia Fusion 2 but in other games like S4 League it does, i'm thinking that it's a keyboard issue but, how some games solved it then..?

Answer (score 0):

How many keys do u press at the same time.
If you are pressing to many at the same time u will get 'Keyboard ghosting':
http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx

Now if that's not the case, I would like to see what your `Move(Direction.Up)` does.

I would personally not use a for switch but:

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
{
     velocity.Y = 0f;
     velocity.X = 2f;                
}
```

Put this is in the update from your Player class(in case you didn't know :S)

Comment: It seems to be a keyboard ghosting issue. I think there is no solution except changing the controls of the game.